# In nichrome wire do adding more chrome increase tensile strength?

Tags: metals

If i add 60% chrome and 40% nickel will the strength increase? I have reading somewhere it should increase to upto 800-1000 MPa. But does this also make it less hest resistant and brittle? I am using this wire cause of the large heat resistance but i need it to also witstand a great deal of pressure ( 10,000 psi+ ) so i need a balance of both.

Comment: 80%Ni 20%Cr is a common nichrome alloy. This composition keeps the alloy in the fcc phase. Going to 40%Ni 60%Cr places the composition in a two-phase region, either bcc Cr plus Ni2Cr or bcc Cr plus fcc Ni. For consistent electrical, thermal, and mechanical properties you should stay in a single phase region. You might look at other alloys (commonly including Fe) that might have better mechanical properties. Also, if you are concerned about hydrostatic pressure, 10kpsi isn't that much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the chromium is what you want to add...

> The introduction of small amounts (<7%) of chromium to nickel increase
> the sensitivity of the nickel chromium alloy to oxidation. This is
> because the diffusion rate of oxygen in the scale is increased. This
> trend reverses after addition levels increase above 7% chromium and
> increases up to an addition level of approximately 30%. Above this
> level, there is little change.

This article can be found [Here](http://www.nickel-alloys.net/nickel_chrome_alloys.html)

I am not a expert at this but I believe adding more chromium to this will just increase sensitivity.

*EDIT* I would also recommend checking out kanthal, isotan (ferrous based) or constantan (copper based alloy) wire, some being stronger. Also search about different gauges of the wire.

I would recommend posting on chemistry for better answers.